# How to hide the header of a tableview in TornadoFX?

Tags: tableview, tornadofx

Is there a tornadofx-way to hide the header row of a tableview?
How do I do that?

Thanks. :-)

I tried finding a header property of some kind in tableview but there is none. Do I have to do it via css/style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a TornadoFX specific function that does that, but you can create a stylesheet, or even an inline stylesheet inside the TableView definition to take care of it:

```
stylesheet {
    Stylesheet.columnHeaderBackground {
        maxHeight = 0.px
        prefHeight = 0.px
        minHeight = 0.px
    }
}
```

Written in an external type safe stylesheet that would look like:

```
class Styles : Stylesheet() {
    companion object {
        val tableNoHeader by cssclass()
    }

    init {
        tableNoHeader {
            maxHeight = 0.px
            prefHeight = 0.px
            minHeight = 0.px
        }
    }
}
```

Now you just need to add the `Styles.tableNoHeader` css class to your TableView.

Oh, and remember to add the stylesheet to your App constructor :)